# why day in Date() start from 2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, to-json

why day must be start from **2** ?!?

```
new Date(2014,0,2).toJSON().slice(0,10)  // return: "2014-01-01"

new Date(2014,0,1).toJSON().slice(0,10)  // return: "2013-12-31"
```

my browser: **Google Chrome**, Version **23**.0.1271.97

Comment: definitely does not have the same value in my chrome version 35.0.1916.114

Comment: u mean is bug in chrome version 23!! lol thnx

Comment: I am using Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 too, but it does show "2014-01-01" for the first date

Comment: yes , is true in  Ver: **35**.0.1916.114